# Can two Process on a Linux running on two different users use same instructions?

Tags: process, linux-kernel

Read this from the textbook "Understanding Kernels"

"If the same program, say an editor, is needed simultaneously by several users, the program is loaded into memory only once, and its instructions can be shared by all of the users who need it. Its data, of course, must not be shared, because each user will have separate data. This kind of shared address space is done automatically by the kernel to save memory."

My doubt is Is it possible for me to start program like Photoshop on my user account and i switch account to access my brother's account and start Photoshop. Is anything shared here? Does the above para hold good? 
Let's say the OS is Linux.

Comment: The read only part of the executable file (such as the code) is memory mapped to process executing the program, and that part would normally be shared between all running instances of the program.

Comment: I seee.. Think i got it. Thanks :)